# VBA Connecting to SQL Server 2017 - Error(Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection)

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel-2013, sql-server-2017

WE use a spreadsheet to collect and distribute various data into sheets for company use.

Use were using MS Excel 2013 and an early version of MS SQL Server
Which worked perfectly without any errors, here is the code from our VBA file:

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command 
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset 

Set con = New ADODB.Connection 
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command 
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset 

MyConStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=sqlserver\SQL;Initial Catalog=MYDB;user id=sa;password=Mon87653day9856" 
con.Open MyConStr
```

Now we have upgraded to SQL Server 2017, and we get the error.
**Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection**

I have tried looking at pipes and changing the order, still get the error.

I have downloaded the new MSOLEDBSQL driver and still get the error.

I have tried the trusted connection and time out settings and still get the error.

Any one got any ideas?

Comment: Forgot - If i chose to run the code after the error has stopped it, i click debug and then run the code it all works perfectly, odd one

Comment: I can connect to the SQL Server using the Management Studio from both the Server and the Computer which will be running this code, with no issues

Answer (score -1):

***Edited***

I am not sure if this was a mistake in your posting or in your original code, but you are missing the terminating quotation marks at the end of your connection string (*I would put this in the comments but don't have a high enough reputation*).

Also, in the past, I would have to specify the IP address of the server in order to establish the connection to the server. May be worth a try.

Comment: Hi - it was a typo apologies - now corrected.

I have tried the IP Address and it still happens.